# Is it appropriate to tell people that you need to be treated like a starter?

Tags: discussion

I am new to coding in general. I have some but little experience in coding skills that the average user in stackoverflow has.

Is it therefore correct to tell someone that I am a 'noob' and not to judge me, or not to treat me like someone who has been studying computer for a long time?

Comment: No one needs to know anything at all about you. All we want to see is a clear problem statement, relevant code, and what you've tried. Everything else detracts from the question. If you want a good quick answer, people should be able to quickly read and understand your issue and the research you've done. Then your code can do the rest of the talking.

Comment: Nothing needs  to be answered on SO , everything has been ^

Comment: Questions let us know by their content how clueless the asker is.  No need to tell us again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a couple of years on this site I'd be tempted to advise you **not** to admit your inexperience. Too many questions on this site start with some variation of *'I'm new to...'*, and go on to ask a question that's poorly researched, incomplete, duplicated or just trivial. My mouse is heading for the close button as soon as I see the words.

That's not to say that newcomers don't ask good questions. Asking a decent question is *hard*, and rightly so. If you can master it, newbie or old hack, you deserve credit for doing so. If you can't, the downvotes should, and probably will, flow.

Answer (score 18):

No. Just get to the point of your question. It doesn't matter if you're a n00b or not. We'll figure it out if you are, and most of us don't care. Just ask a good question that you're stuck on after attempting something and doing some research.